# MapR and Java bug

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapr, bigdata

I am using java, spring boot and MapR 5.2

```
QueryCondition cond = MapRDB
        .newCondition()
        .in("propertyName", searchedStrings)
        .build();

    List<Document> docs = jsonStore.query(cond);
```

That query is working fine returing the joined result that I am expecting (if we have 2 records in the database that have propertyName=1 and propertyName=2, and we have 1 and 2 in searched strings - both are returned)

HOWEVER if we search by id:

```
QueryCondition cond = MapRDB
            .newCondition()
            .in("_id", searchedStrings)
            .build();

        List<Document> docs = jsonStore.query(cond);
```

- the query is returing only 1 document always (even if we have more matching)
Do you have any info about that behaviour? is it a bug or...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: noone knows? or any links with similar bugs or something